# RubyMine should autofill instance variables

Tags: rubymine

I would like rubymine to be able to autocomplete for instance methods.

```
def get_db
    return Mysql::new(DB_HOST, "x", "x", "x")
end

DB = get_db
```

if i where to type in

```
DB.
```

I should get all the methods of the Mysql Object.
Do i need to do something so that RubyMine can correctly do this?

Answer (score -1):

No IDE can deduce what `get_db` will return (for a dynamic language)